# Unable to join .aa, .ab , .ac, .ad files to make a single file

Tags: file

I have 6 files of .aa, .ab type extensions. The name of one file is  - 
ProActiveScheduling-4.0.0-BETA1.zip.aa

other 5 files are the same with extensions .ab, .ac, .ad, .ae, .af

Can somebody tell me how to join them.

Thanks for telling.

Comment: Is this a single zip file which has been split into sections?

Answer (score 3):

Not the best question indeed, but this is for others like me who came here before finding a solution elsewhere:

The `*.aa`, `*.ab` and so forth are typically created by the `split` function on Linux or macOS:

```
$ split -b 100M Big\ File.mp4 small.
```

This splits `Big File.mp4` into `small.aa`, `small.ab`, `small.ac`, etc., which are all 100 MB maximum.

To merge them again (which answers the question), in a terminal on Linux or macOS do:

```
$ cat small.?? > Big_Again.mp4
```

The question marks substitute the two characters `aa`, `ab`, etc. The files `Big File.mp4` and `Big_Again.mp4` will be identical.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how the parts (files) were created.

1) If the different parts were created by a packager (like WinRar, WinZip, 7zip) try to open the first file with such a tool and see if it shows you the contents of the zip-file or displays you an error message.

2) If the different parts are just splitted you can easily join them on a windows system by typing the following command on the command line:
`type file1.zip.aa file1.zip.ab file1.zip.ac ... > file.zip`